# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre los verbos Patch y Put?

Tags: http, https

No quiero llenarlos de texto inútil, ya que la pregunta está bien clara. En la facultad me enseñaron a usar el verbo Patch para hacer modificaciones y en internet veo que generalmente se usa Put. Me gustaría que alguien me explique la diferencia entre ambos.

Saludos!

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta te puede ser de utilidad https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241893/rest-api-patch-or-put

Comment: yo recomendaría usar patch  para evitar excepciones en tiempo de ejecución. con el put reemplazas toda la entidad pero no te salva de errores en tiempo de ejecucion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aquí algunas definiciones:

**PUT** se define en la Sección 9.6 RFC 2616 :

> El método PUT solicita que la entidad adjunta se almacene bajo el URI
>   de solicitud proporcionado. Si el URI de solicitud se refiere a un
>   recurso ya existente, la entidad adjuntada DEBERÍA considerarse como
>   una versión modificada de la que reside en el servidor de origen . Si
>   el URI de solicitud no apunta a un recurso existente, y ese URI puede
>   definirse como un recurso nuevo por el agente de usuario solicitante,
>   el servidor de origen puede crear el recurso con ese URI.

**PATCH** se define en RFC 5789 :

> El método PATCH solicita que se aplique un conjunto de cambios
>   descritos en la entidad de solicitud al recurso identificado por el
>   URI de Solicitud.

Te comparto esta referencias que te será de mucha utilidad:

[PATCH & PUT](https://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/)

[PUT vs PATCH](https://code.i-harness.com/es/q/1b2419a)

Answer (score 5):

Es simple, PUT es reemplazo completo de la entidad, PATCH sólo de una parte

Comment: podrías dar un ejemplo o una referencia de esi que dices?

Comment: Este es mucho mas claro...